# Suppose A and B are sets. If $|A| = m$ and $|B| = n$, then how many relations are there from $A$ to $B$?

Tags: proof-writing, relations

Coudn't I say that it is $m\times n$ relations because the collection of all ordered pairs is the Cartesian Product $A\times B$?

Comment: A relation is just a subset of $A\times B$. What is the cardinality of the powerset of $A\times B$?

Comment: Would that be $2^{mn}$?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: So then the answer is $2^{mn}$?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$